# Is it possible to control a matplotlib graph using a Tkinter Scrollbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, scrollbar

I would like to make an equivalent of the function FuncAnimation from matplotlib.animation, in which I could control the current plotted data using the scrollbar.

Say you have a data array which contains data points to be plotted at each time i. When using FuncAnimation, you first need to define a function ( here animate(i) ) which will be called for each time i = 1 to len(data[:,0]) :

```
def animate(i):
    ax.plot(data[i,:])

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100, frames=len(data[:,0]))
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

but you cannot control the time i, like with a play/stop functionality. What I would like to do is to call the function animate(i), with i being the position of the scrollbar.

I found this example ( using the events from matplotlib:
https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/users/event_handling.html )
but the mpl_connect doesn't have a "scrollbar_event".

```
import tkinter
from random import randint
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

#create figure
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.imshow(np.array([[0,10],[23,40]]))

#create canvas with figure
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

def on_key_press(event):
    ax.clear()
    ax.imshow(np.array([[randint(0,30),randint(0,30)],[randint(0,30),randint(0,30)]]))
    canvas.draw_idle()
    key_press_handler(event, canvas)
    print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))

#connect canvas to event function
canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)

def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the scroll functionality is given by matplotlib widgets !!
The example below works fine :

```
import matplotlib
import tkinter as Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from myPytHeader import *


matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")

fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(8, 6))
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)


nDt = nbLines("grid.dat")
nDx = nbGridPoints("grid.dat")
grid = np.zeros( (nDt,nDx) ) ; loadData("grid.dat", grid)
valu = np.zeros( (nDt,nDx) ) ; loadData("valu.dat", valu)

ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

ax_time = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.78, 0.03])
s_time = Slider(ax_time, 'Time', 0, nDt, valinit=0, valstep=1)


def update(val):
    frame = int(s_time.val)
    ax.clear()
    ax.set(xlim=(-0.05, 1.05), ylim=(-0.05, 1.25))
    ax.grid()
    ax.scatter(grid[frame,:], valu[frame,:], color='b', marker='.')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

s_time.on_changed(update)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

After all these years I've found solutions to my problems here, I am in debt !!!
Here is the final solution I came with.
I hope it can be useful to someone someday somehow !!

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


# load data
nDt = 1000
nDx = 400
grd = np.zeros( (nDt,nDx) )
val = np.zeros( (nDt,nDx) )
for t in np.arange(nDt):
    for x in np.arange(nDx):
        grd[t,x] = x / nDx
        val[t,x] = (x / nDx) * (t/nDt) * np.sin(10 * 2*np.pi * (t-x)/nDt)


matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")

fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(8, 6))
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
ax.set(xlim=(-0.05, 1.05), ylim=(-1.05, 1.05))
ax.grid()
scat = ax.scatter(grd[0,:], val[0,:], color='b', marker='.')

ax_time = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.78, 0.03])
s_time = Slider(ax_time, 'Time', 0, nDt, valinit=0, valstep=1)
i_anim = 0
i_relative = 0
i_current = 0

def updateGraph(i):
    y_i = val[i,:]
    scat.set_offsets(np.c_[grd[i,:], y_i])


def updateFromAnim(i):
    global i_anim
    global i_current
    global i_relative
    i_anim = i
    i_current = i + i_relative
    s_time.set_val(i_current)
    updateGraph(i_current)

def updateFromScroll(val):
    global i_anim
    global i_current
    global i_relative
    i_relative = int(s_time.val) - i_anim
    i_current = int(s_time.val)
    updateGraph(i_current)

def onClick():
    global anim_running
    if anim_running:
        anim.event_source.stop()
        anim_running = False
    else:
        anim.event_source.start()
        anim_running = True

start_button = tk.Button(root, text="START/STOP", command=onClick)
start_button.pack()

anim_running = True
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, updateFromAnim, interval=100, frames=nDt)


s_time.on_changed(updateFromScroll)

tk.mainloop()
```